# Autofac Configuration for constructor with KeyFilter attribute

Tags: json, configuration, autofac

I am trying to use Autofac Configuration to create a Service object.

```
public class Service : IService
{
        public Service([KeyFilter("eod")]ISimpleMongoClient eodClient,
            [KeyFilter("live")]ISimpleMongoClient liveClient
            ) : base(config)
        {
            _eodClient = eodClient;
            _liveClient =  liveClient;
        }
}

public class SimpleMongoClient : ISimpleMongoClient
{
    public SimpleMongoClient(string connectionString, string database)
    {
        IMongoClient client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        MongoDatabase = client.GetDatabase(database);
    }
}
```

Somehow with the following configuration, it is not able to resolve the ISimpleMongoClient parameters correctly. What else am I missing?

```
{
  "components": [
    {
      "type": "Service, TestProject",
      "services": [
        {
          "type": "IService, TestProject"
        }
      ],
      "instanceScope": "single-instance"
    },
    {
      "type": "SimpleMongoClient, TestProject",
      "services": [
        {
          "type": "ISimpleMongoClient, TestProject",
          "key": "eod"
        }
      ],
      "parameters": {
        "connectionString": "mongodb://localhost:27017/?readPreference=primary",
        "database": "eod"
      },
      "instanceScope": "single-instance"
    },
    {
      "type": "SimpleMongoClient, TestProject",
      "services": [
        {
          "type": "ISimpleMongoClient, TestProject",
          "key": "live"
        }
      ],
      "parameters": {
        "connectionString": "mongodb://localhost:27017/?readPreference=primary",
        "database": "live"
      },
      "instanceScope": "single-instance"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use the `KeyFilter` attribute you need to register the thing doing the filtering [with the `WithAttributeFiltering()`](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html#keyfilterattribute) extension. You can't do that through configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do you think if it is worth make it doable via configuration? Shall I raise this as a feature request?

Comment: No, configuration isn't supposed to be a feature-for-feature match with the programmatic setup. The recommended solution if you need to do that is to write an Autofac module with the extra programmatic bits and configure the module. See the docs for examples.

Comment: @TravisIllig where is this specific example?

Comment: @TravisIllig I have another question about this question, if `key` is not used for `KeyFilter` so what is `key` in configuration file? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77458290/1539100

Comment: @TravisIllig So, Why existing `key` in configuration file?